# Is it better to get water-resistant camera bag for cycling, or upgrade to a weather-resistant camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, equipment-protection, camera-bag, weather-sealing

I used to do a little photography a while back (when the 350D first came out) and I'm thinking of getting into it again to take the some landscape shots during my other hobby of cycling.

With the weather being terrible and unpredictable at times in the UK, I need some kind of water resistant bag or case. I have a basic LowePro bag but it doesn't look up to the job of keeping my equipment dry.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what would suit this kind of thing best? Something with a bit of support or shell in case I happen to fall off would be a bonus but not essential.

Am I better off bringing my inevitable purchase of a more modern camera forward? Newer camera's like the 7D seem to be pretty resilient to this kind of thing right out of the box.

Comment: Handlebar bags by Ortlieb and Vaude are waterproof.

Comment: What kind of bag, exactly?

Comment: Lowepro has some waterproof backpacks, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need anything specially designed for cycling, what are you doing with your other gear you take cycling, mobile phone etc?

It depends on the size of the bag but you can get different size covers which go over the top or a large zip lock bag. It's also possible to buy a range of camera backpacks which are either waterproof or come with a cover.

Or how about a lunch box in a rucksack?

These days you can get something for every part of photography, but it's often not used enough and turns into a waste of money.